# About finding the common diagonalizing similarity transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, spectral-theory, nonlinear-optimization

Say I have $2k$ matrices $M_{a_1b_1}$, $M_{a_2b_2}$,..,$M_{a_kb_k}$ and their negatives. Here $M_{a_ib_i}$ is such that it has $0$ everywhere except that it has $1$ at $(a_i,b_i)$ and $(b_i,a_i)$ entry. Also all the $k$ $a$s and $b$s are distinct $2k$ integers.

One can argue that these are mutually commuting $2k$ matrices and hence are simultaneously diagonalizable.

- But can one algebraically specify as to what is the similarity transformation that will simultaneously diagonalize them? (and their diagonal forms?)

Comment: Commuting matrices are only simultaneously diagonalizable if they are each diagonalizable in the first place.  These are not.

Comment: They are, however, simultaneously upper-triangularizable.

Comment: How do you see that these are not diagonalizable?

Comment: All these $M$s are real-symmetric matrices. Why shouldn't each of them be diagonalizable!?

Comment: Oh, whoops, I didn't read the question correctly; I thought the matrices were upper/lower triangular. I guess you're right then.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the canonical orthonormal basis.
Let $U$ be the matrix whose columns are given by $u_1,\dots,u_n$, where
$$
u_{2j-1} = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} (e_{a_j} + e_{b_j})
\qquad j = 1,\dots,k\\
u_{2j} = \frac 1{\sqrt 2} (e_{a_j} - e_{b_j})
\qquad j = 1,\dots,k
$$
and $u_{2k+1},\dots,u_n$ are chosen so that the columns $u_j$ are orthonormal.  Then $U$ is unitary, and for each $M$, the matrix $U^{-1}MU = U^*MU$ will be diagonal.

The matrix $M_{a_jb_j}$ is taken to the diagonal matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
0\\
&\ddots\\
&&0\\
&&&1\\
&&&&-1\\
&&&&&0\\
&&&&&& \ddots\\
&&&&&&& 0
}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. (1) Won't the location of the $1$ and the $-1$ in the diagonal form of $M_{a_i b_i}$ depend on $a_i$ and $b_i$ ? (2) Can we fix a canonical $U$ that will always work? Because I need to know "a" U fully for my purposes.